# " init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encodingPython runtime state: core initialized"

Tags: python, ubuntu, hadoop, mapreduce

I saw some posts with incomplete information to solve the problem. I assure you I will try my best to provide all information. I am new to using python in ubuntu.

I googled the error but no solution found. 
I have python 2.7 installed then also error is saying about 3.8. What could be the reason behind this? [python version check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbDuG.png)
Based on this I looked into /usr/bin and I found [python 2.7 and 3.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrK7z.png). But I never installed 3.8, so how did it appear? Due to this I can't start hadoop, spark, hive or pyspark.

One way I can think of is deleting PYTHONHOME in  varaiable bash, will it mess anything else?

Following the steps mentioned in [this post](https://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/)

Host OS: win 10
Guest OS: Ubuntu 20
Hypervisor: VMWare Workstation 15
Goal: Map-Reduce program in python
Files: mapper.py, reducer.py [ located at /home/user/]

So far completed:
mapper.py

```
#!/use/bin/env python
"""mapper.py"""

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        print '%s\t%s' % (word,1)
```

reducer.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""reducer.py"""

from operator import itemgetter
import sys

current_word = None
current_count = 0
word = None

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    word, count = line.split('\t', 1)
    try:
        count = int(count)
    except ValueError:
        continue

    if current_word == word:
        current_count += count
    else:
        if current_word:
            print '%s\t%s' % (current_word, current_count)
        current_count = count
        current_word = word


if current_word == word:
    print '%s\t%s' % (current_word, current_count)
```

To test mappe.py command used:

```
echo "foo foo quxx labs foo bar quxx" | /home/jordan/mapper.py
```

to copy file from localsystem to hdfs

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/jordan/Downloads/judicial_dataset_predictions.csv
```

or

```
hadoop fs -put /home/jordan/Downloads/judicial_dataset_predictions.csv
```

Here is the error pic: [error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nUFx.png)

Please someone help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` to `/usr/lib/python3.8` as described in https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin It did not work, same error. I double checked PYTHONPATH using echo $PYTHONPATH command giving output as " :/usr/lib/python2.7:/usr/lib/python3.8:/usr/lib/python3.8 ". Does that mean python 2.7 is still in env varible?

Comment: Yes, it does. The `:` are the separators.

Comment: what can be done to remove python2.7 from PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Check files listed here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249922/214311.

Comment: That helped actually. Thanks. Just to make sure I am on right track, when I run command "hadoop fs -put Localfilepath" if you get error saying " hadoop: command not found ", does that mean I need to start hadoop first and then run put command?

Comment: I know nothing of Hadoop. I guess, though, that hadoop binary is not in your curent directory. It might be a `PATH` issue, or something with your environment, or container.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!! My life sucks, it was working fine when I installed it for the first time